# Read from csv with, except phrase in " "

Tags: python, csv

I have csv file with rows like:

6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male

I read this file with using csv:

```
import csv
data_iter = csv.reader(dest_f, delimiter=',', quotechar='\n')
```

As a result, i obtained list, where **"Moran** and  **Mr. James"** are two different values, but I need to get the complete value in brackets **"Moran, Mr. James"**

Comment: Shouldn't it be `quotechar='"'`? `\n` is supposed to be the line separator, not the character that is used to enclose certain values in. The quote char should escape `,` in values. If there are `"` in the values, they should be escaped as `""` or `\"`.

Comment: what do you expect `quotechar='\n'` to do?

Comment: Sorry, that was too stupid. Of course `quotechar` should be `'"'`, and here should be additional parameter `doubleqoute=True`

Answer (score 1):

Don't specify the quote character (which you have done incorrectly), just let csv.reader use its defaults:

```
import csv
dest_f = [ '6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male' ]
data_iter = csv.reader(dest_f)
print next(data_iter)
```

Result:

```
['6', '0', '3', 'Moran, Mr. James', 'male']
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using **skipinitialspace** ?

```
>>> import csv
>>> dest_f = '6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male'
>>> for line in csv.reader([dest_f], skipinitialspace=True):
...     print line
... 
['6', '0', '3', 'Moran, Mr. James', 'male']
```